# How to adjust the dimension of model？

Tags: modeling

Hi，I have created a model. I want to adjust the dimension of the model. 
Scale was 0.136, 0.136, 0.136 and Dimensions was 1.73164, 1.62762, 2.33337. When I change the size of Diomension in x-achse, the number of x-achse in Scale will be automatic changed. But I just want to change the Dimension and keep the number in Scale not be changed. what should I do？ [image]

Comment: In  local coordinates (vertex coords for mesh)  each edge of the cube is 2 units long. -1 to 1 in each axis. At unit scale (1, 1, 1) and is also its global .dimension. If we set x dimension to 4 it will result in setting scale.x to 2 .  It is still locally dimension 2x2x2. scale (2, 1, 1) and dimension (4, 2, 2)   If we apply that scale (ctrl-A - scale) it will  have local dimension  4x2x2. at unit scale (1, 1, 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimensions is related to changing the scale of the object in Edit mode, if you want to only change dimensions, you can use edit mode and scale it there. Scaling in Object mode will result in changing both dimensions and scale. Hope that helps!

Comment: can you give me a screenshot in Edit Mode？ I changed my model in Edit..But I did not find where can I change dimensions

Comment: can you give me a screenshot in Edit Mode？ I changed my model in Edit..But I did not find where can I change dimensions

Comment: When you scale the model in edit mode as you would in object, it will only change the dimensions but the scale will remain the same as it was before you entered edit mode

Comment: i know what you mean. But I did not find where can I adjust the dimesion in edit mode. That is the problem

Comment: You can just scale it as usual, clicking on Scale on the left side of the viewport (if you don't have that tab open, press T), or using the shortcut S, if you have the default shortcuts